# How to read json data with namespace in jquery

Tags: jquery, json

i am fetching json data using jquery and i am getting json data like this

```
{
        "im:name": {
                        "label": "Meon"
                    },
         "rights": {
                        "label": "© 2012 Manbolo"
                    },
        "im:price": {
                        "label": "$0.99"
                    }
    }
```

i am able to read **"rights"** tag **label** data but dont know how to read **"im:name"**.
when i am trying to read its giving **undefined** ERROR .

Please suggest me how to read data. i am using **jquery** only.

Thanks

Comment: How are you trying to read the value?

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker i am reading rights tag value successfully like- data.rights.label;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use subscript notation instead of dot notation.

```
data["im:name"].label
```

Comment: @Roopchand, it will be of great help if you can share the code.

Comment: $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "http://someurl.com",
     dataType: "json",
     success: function(data)
     { var rights=data.rights.label;(working) and var rights=data.['im:name'].label;(not working) }    });

Comment: @Roopchand the code should be data['im:name'].label, instead of data.['im:name'].label

Answer (score 0):

You can easily go to the console, where you display your object, right mouse button on the property that you want to find and "Copy property path"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rfszt.png)